# How to generate Jmeter dashboard report through java coding. ( not windows or shell command)

Tags: java, jmeter

I have to generate Jmeter dashboard report through java coding.   Below java code, I had used to generate a normal jmeter report. I have to generate a 
 dashboard report through java.

```
  public class JMeterFromExistingJMX {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        // JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties
        ("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();// log
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        FileInputStream in = new 
         FileInputStream
       ("/path/to/your/jmeter/extras/Test.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
        in.close();

        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post the mentioned java code, right?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I have added now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all you need to produce a .jtl results file prior to generating reporting dashboard so make sure to add the following code block to your function:

   ```
   Summariser summer = null;
   String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
   if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
       summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
   }
   String logFile = "/path/to/result.jtl";
   ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
   logger.setFilename(logFile);

   testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
   ```
2. Then you need to set HTML Reporting Dashboard destination:

   ```
   JMeterUtils.setProperty(JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "/where/you/want/the/dashboard/to/be/generated");
   ```
3. And finally you can call [ReportGenerator](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/ReportGenerator.html) class like:

   ```
   ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile,null);
   generator.generate();
   ```

Full code just in case:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

import static org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY;

public class RunJMeterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/test.jmx"));
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }
        String logFile = "/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/result.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
        JMeterUtils.setProperty(JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "/path/to/dashboard");
        ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile, null);
        generator.generate();
    }
}
```

References:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please share dependency and import for above code. I have used ApacheJMeter_core version 4. Unable to import all the supporting class

Comment: Updated the code to represent full class. With regards to dependencies - it depends on what components do you use, in case of doubts plug in everything from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter