# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in jMeter code for Report Generator

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, dashboard, jmeter-5.0

I am writing a jMeter test plan from java code.
I took this code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968942/how-to-generate-jmeter-dashboard-report-through-java-coding-not-windows-or-sh?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Except i keep having an exception and I am not sure where I went wrong.

It was working for a while but as soon as I decided to change the domain and port number etc it got confusing , althou the problem has to do with the ReportGenerator.

I believe the null exception goes for the parameters in the reportgenerator function but it doesn't make sense as it's possible to have a null value.

Some clarifying would be helpful.
I will put the code .

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        //Set jmeter home for the jmeter utils to load
        File jmeterHome = new File("C:\\tmp");
        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
            File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "jmeter.properties");
            if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                //JMeter Engine
                StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
                JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
              //  JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
                JMeterUtils.initLocale();

                // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
                HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

                // First HTTP Sampler - open uttesh.com
                HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
                examplecomSampler.setDomain("google.com");
                examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
                examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
                examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
                examplecomSampler.setName("Open google.com");
                examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
                examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


                // Loop Controller
                LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
                loopController.setLoops(1);
                loopController.setFirst(true);
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
                loopController.initialize();

                // Thread Group
                ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
                threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
                threadGroup.setNumThreads(100);
                threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
                threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

                // Test Plan
                TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");

                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
                testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

                // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
                testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
                HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
                threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);

                // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format

                try{
                    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream("C:\\tmp\\jmeter_api_sample.jmx"));
                }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
                }


                //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
                // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
                Summariser summer = null;
                String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
                if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
                }


                String logFile = "C:\\tmp\\result.jtl";
                ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
                logger.setFilename(logFile);
                testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
                jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                jmeter.run();


                try {
                    JMeterUtils.setProperty(JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "C:\\tmp\\report");
                    ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile,null);
                    generator.generate();
                }catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }catch (GenerationException ge){
                    System.out.println(ge.getMessage());
                }


                System.out.println("Test completed. See " + jmeterHome + slash + "report.jtl file for results");
                System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + slash + "jmeter_api_sample.jmx");
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

        System.err.println("jmeterHome property is not set or pointing to incorrect location");
        System.exit(1);


    }
}
```

and this is the error given. (I am working with IntelliJ IDEA)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.createStatistic(JsonExporter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:262)
>     at test.main(test.java:126)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**line 126 is generator.generate();**

**Edit : The solution i found was that my logFile aka resultcollector was empty and that is due to the difference between the versions of the dependencies of each library. Always check those.**

Comment: Which line in the code you pasted is line 126 from `test.main(test.java:126)`?

Comment: generator.generate();

Comment: Could it be possible that the ReportGenerator constructor can't find the logFile you specified? I wonder if it's worth confirming that it exists, and if it does, trying to move this file to your Documents directory (for example) and using that path instead.

Comment: i found out why. the problem is that the logFile comes out blank therefor the egenrator considers it as null too.